# How can I get repeatable field values of a Document Type (WCM) via Application Display Template (ADT)?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, freemarker

I have this [Document Type Structure](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-2/document-types-and-metadata-sets):

[image]

I can get the value of the fields that do not have a children (in this example the field with the name *Field*):

```
<#if imageMimeTypes?seq_contains(entry.getMimeType()) >
    <#assign fileEntryType = DLFileEntryTypeService.getFileEntryType(fileEntryTypeId) />
    <#assign dlFileVersion = DLFileVersionService.getLatestFileVersion(fileEntry.getUserId(), fileEntry.getFileEntryId()) />
    <#assign fieldsMap = fileEntry.getFieldsMap(dlFileVersion.getFileVersionId()) />

    <#list fieldsMap?keys as structureKey>
        <#list fieldsMap[structureKey].iterator() as field>
            <#if field.getName() == 'Field'>
                <#assign Field = field.getValue() />
            </#if>
        </#list>
    </#list>

    Value: ${Field}
</#if>
```

But when I have a repeatable field with children fields I can't get neither the value of the repeatable field nor the value of its children.

```
<#list fieldsMap?keys as structureKey>
    <#list fieldsMap[structureKey].iterator() as field>
        <#if field.getName() == 'Repeatable_field'>
            <#assign RepeatableField = field.getName() />
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#list>

Value: ${RepeatableField}
```

I get this error:

> Expecting a string, date or number here, Expression RepeatableField
>   is instead a freemarker.template.SimpleSequence

---

**UPDATE:**

I managed to get the value of `Repeatable_field` using **`field.getValues(locale)`** method.
But I still can't get the value of its children:

```
<#list fieldsMap?keys as structureKey>
    <#list fieldsMap[structureKey].iterator() as field>
        <#if field.getName() == 'Repeatable_field'>
            <#assign repeatableFieldValues = field.getValues(locale) />
            <#list repeatableFieldValues as val>
                <#assign Field = val /><#-- parent Value -->
                <#-- assign childrenField = val.Children_field.getValue() --><#-- children Value -->
            </#list>
        </#if>
    </#list>
</#list>
```

Comment: As all of the variables are backed by Java objects, it has helped me to just print `.getClass().getName()` during creation/debugging of those templates, then look up the printed interface for options on what to call in each case. Or set a debugger breakpoint at some of the more obvious getters, then inspect the other fields in that class.

Comment: Thank you so much @OlafKock

Comment: In my CMS templates I usually use `$value.getSiblings()` - this is working for child values as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Liferay 7.3, I get the repeatable field values within the ADT in this way:

```html
<#if entries?has_content>
    <#list entries as entry>
        <#if entry.getClassName() == "com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle" >

            <#assign assetRenderer = entry.getAssetRenderer() />
            <#assign article = assetRenderer.getArticle() />
            <#assign articleStructure = article.getDDMStructure() />
            <#assign articleStructureFields = articleStructure.getRootFieldNames() />

            <#assign document = saxReaderUtil.read(article.getContent()) />
            <#assign rootElement = document.getRootElement() />

            <#list articleStructureFields as field>
                <#attempt>
                    <#assign xPathSelectorDocument = saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='${field}']") />
                    <#assign fieldContent = xPathSelectorDocument.selectSingleNode(rootElement).getStringValue() />
                    <#assign fieldNodes   = xPathSelectorDocument.selectNodes(rootElement) />

                    <#if field == 'User'>               <#-- Field - Simple -->
                        <#assign user = fieldContent />
                    <#elseif field == 'Actions'>        <#-- Field - Repeatable -->

                        <#assign listActions = [] />
                        <#list fieldNodes as node>
                            <#assign listActions = listActions + [node.getStringValue()] />
                        </#list>

                    </#if>
                <#recover>Error</#attempt>
            </#list>

            <#-- Field - Simple -->
            ${user}

            <#-- Field - Repeatable -->
            <#list listActions as action>
                ${action}
            </#list>

        </#if>
    </#list>
</#if>
```